# Jquery - random background

Tags: jquery

I have the task - append some  with random background-color each other.

```
$(function(){
        var html = [];
        for (var i=0; i<50; i++) {
        html.push('<div>');
        html.push('</div>');
        }
    $('#ten-square').append(html.join(''));
        $('#ten-square').each(function() { 
        var random_color = '#' + Math.floor((Math.random() * (999999 - 100000) + 100000));
        $('#ten-square div').css({'background-color' : random_color});
        });
    })
```

The blocks have any reload different color, but all of them have the same color.
Help me please. 1-block(red), 2-block(green) etc.

Answer (score 1):

The `$('#ten-square div')` selector isn't doing what you think it is: rather than pulling the current `div` in your loop, it's setting the background color on all the `div`s under `$('#ten-square')`.

What you're looking for is something like this, which operates on the elements as you loop:

```
$('#ten-square').each(function(i, el) 
{ 
    var random_color = '#' + Math.floor((Math.random() * (999999 - 100000) + 100000));
    $(el).css({'background-color' : random_color});
});
```

Additionally, you're ignoring a bunch of possible colors (anything between #AAAAAA and #FFFFFF, among others) using that randomization method. I'd try selecting 3 random numbers between 0 and 255 and using those for an `rgb()` color instead.

Comment: Thanks. You variant is working. And Thanks for "RGB". Did`nt know about this. You are help me to find a work)

Answer (score 1):

try this code :)

```js
$(function(){
    var html = [];
    for (var i=0; i<50; i++) {
        html.push('<div>');
        html.push('</div>');
    }
    $('#ten-square').append(html.join(''));
    $('#ten-square div').each(function() { 
        var random_color = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
        $(this).css({'background-color' : random_color});
    });
})
```

```css
#ten-square div {
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ten-square"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - it works. I have new knowledge - some `` lost) Thanks.